Audio stream plays on Alexa app but not on echo dot
I’ve created an Alexa audio player skill to stream longform audio (.m3u8 playlist of segments).
It works great on the Alexa app, but I cannot get any audio on the echo dot.
Any reason why it would work on one and not the other? Do they have different decoding abilities?
Tried running my skill on both Alex app and echo dot. I expected audio on both

All my alexa custom skills were working perfect with audioplayer on Alexa App, Echo Dot / Show and Fire TV.
5 weeks ago i notice the same problem: It plays only in Alexa App
I'm still working on and it seems a problem with the audio URL for some live streams with m3u8 format.
If i use an mp3 file in a public URL, AudioPlayer play perfect on Alexa App, Echo Dot, Show and FireTV.
But, some m3u8 file formats only in Alexa App.
I will keep tuned on this issue.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
